# The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I am getting the following error message randomly, whenever I am trying to execute the below stored procedure through the .net core application.

**Error Message:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_UpdateInfo] (@xx NVARCHAR(50),
            @yy NVARCHAR(200),@Id int, @ab NVARCHAR(max),
            @ac int,
            @ad NVARCHAR(200), @ae NVARCHAR(200),@af NVARCHAR(100),
            @ag NVARCHAR(100),@zz NVARCHAR(MAX), @DateTime DATETIME)
  AS
   BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SAVE TRANSACTION UpdateInfo;
BEGIN TRY
    --First update 
    UPDATE XXTable
    SET XX = @xx
    WHERE YY=@yy;

    --Update the XXTable object with updated information 
    UPDATE XXTable
    SET ZZ = @zz,
    AB = @ab,
    AC= @ac,
    AD= @ad,
    AE= @ae,
    AF= @af,
    AG= @ag,
    DateTime= @DateTime
    WHERE Id=@Id;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION UpdateInfo; -- rollback to MySavePoint
    END
END CATCH
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

END

So, can anyone please help me out on this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `SAVE TRANSACTION` here?

Comment: @DavidG, I am using `SAVE TRANSACTION ` for handling failovers.

Comment: Ok @DanGuzman, But why I am getting this issue randomly?

Answer (score 0):

The entire transaction be rolled back with or without the savepoint in the case of a failover. I suggest you simply remove that unneeded complexity here.

Don't know if your code was overly simplified for posting here but your catch block hides the error entirely. One should generally include `THROW;` after the `ROLLBACK` to re-raise the original error and terminate proc execution.